# Make the home button go the middle screen?

Tags: lineageos, wallpaper, 8.1-oreo, trebuchet

With Android 8.1, the wallpaper can cover all three screens. So when you move from the first screen to the second, and from the second to the third, the wallpaper pans to a different part.

This is a cool effect.

How can I make my home button take me to the **second** screen -- in the middle of 1 & 3, so the wallpaper shows the cool stuff when I first launch into my phone.

Comment: Try a different launcher? Trebuchet (the default) is quite short on customization options.

Comment: You definitely need another launcher if the current one doesn't provide such a functionality.